# Custom Parser for Nutch (or open source .NET Crawler)

Tags: asp.net, solr, web-crawler, nutch, solrnet

I have been using Nutch/Solr/SolrNet for my search solutions, I must say, it works a treat. On a new site I'm working on, I am using Master pages, as a result, content in the header and footer is getting indexed and distorts the results. For example, I have a link to the Contact Us page in the header. Now, when I search for 'Contact' the result returns all the pages in the site.

Is there a customizable Nutch parser that i can maybe pass a div id and then it only indexes content inside the div.

Or if there are .NET based crawlers that I can customize.

Comment: I have found [NCrawler](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/), a .net crawler. has 4 * 5star reviews and looks promising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-585
and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-961

BTW you'd get a more relevant audience by posting to the Nutch user list

Comment: Thanks for the links, they will get me going regarding Nutch. I have also decide to use NCrawler (.NET) for some specific situations mainly because I use C#.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a Nutch filter (I like [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html)) to extract only the parts of the page you need to index using DOM manipulation. You can use the [TextExtractor](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/javadoc/net/htmlparser/jericho/TextExtractor.html) class to grab clean text (sans HTML tags) to be used in your index. I usually save that data in custom fields.